# What is the difference between Expo WebBrowser and Expo Webview in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I couldn't find the difference between Expo WebBrowser (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/) and Expo Webview (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/) in React Native?

When should I use Webview instead of WebBrowser ?

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser is a browser with back & forward buttons and uses SFSafariViewController, while WebView is a view to render web content but is not intended for browsing and uses UI/WKWebView. You can build a browser with WebView (Chrome for iOS) but WebBrowser is often convenient.
Quote: James Ide @JI @Expo